# Using custom DataFlow unbounded source on DirectPipelineRunner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm writing a custom DataFlow unbounded data source that reads from Kafka 0.8. I'd like to run it locally using the DirectPipelineRunner. However, I'm getting the following stackstrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no evaluator registered for Read(KafkaDataflowSource)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:700)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:219)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:102)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:252)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:662)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:374)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:87)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:174)
```

Which makes some sense, as I haven't registered an evaluator for my custom source at any time.

Reading https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK, it seems like only evaluators for *bounded* sources are registered. What's the recommended way to define and register an evaluator for an custom unbounded source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DirectPipelineRunner` currently runs over bounded input only. We are actively working on removing this restriction, and expect to release it shortly.

In the meanwhile, you can trivially turn any `UnboundedSource` into a `BoundedSource`, for testing purposes, by using `withMaxNumRecords`, as in the following example:

```
UnboundedSource<String> unboundedSource  = ...; // make a Kafka source
PCollection<String> boundedKafkaCollection =
    p.apply(Read.from(unboundedSource).withMaxNumRecords(10));
```

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/93) for more details.

---

Separately, there are several efforts on contributing the Kafka connector.  You may want to engage with us and other contributors about that via [our GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/96).

Comment: Basically we're on an old version of kafka with the older consumer API, so our efforts on the connector are currently a bit useless to you :-) We'd hope we get our version of kafka updated and end up using a more standard connector soon.